# Execute same query with different table names

Tags: php

I have an array with some table names and a predefined SQL query.
I want the execute the same query on all of the tables in that array. My approach was to traverse the table array and to replace the current table name with the next one (`+1`):

```
$tabs = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"); // array of tables

$query = "SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `abc`"; // example query

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($tabs); $i++){
    // ... execute ...

    echo $query; // for debugging

    $query = str_replace ( $tabs [$i], $tabs [$i+1], $query ); // replacing table names
}
```

This is the output:

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `abc`
SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `def`
SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `ghi`
SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `jkl`
```

But in that case, it comes to that situation, where it tries to access an index that doesn't exist (in this case it' s `4`).
So this error (or notice) occurs:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 4 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a marker in your query and replace it for each tables, like this :

```
<?php

$tabs = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"); // array of tables
$query = "SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `%my_table%` "; // example query

foreach($tabs as $tab) {
    $query = str_replace("%my_table%", $tab, $query);
    echo $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with an template query.

```
$tabs = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"); // array of tables

$tmp_query = "SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `%table%`"; // template query

echo $tmp_query ; // for debugging

foreach($tabs as $tab){

    $query = str_replace ('%table%', $tab, $tmp_query  ); // replacing table names

    echo $query ; // for debugging

    // ... execute ...
}
```

Comment: `$query = str_replace ('%table%', $tab, $tmp_query ); // replacing table names

    echo $query ;`

Comment: @splash58 oooops

Answer (score 0):

```
$tabs = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'); // array of tables

foreach($tabs as $tab) {
    $query = sprintf('SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `%s`', $tab);

    // do something with $query
}
```

Explanation:

- Single quotes are faster than double quotes.
- sprintf is faster than str_replace and more flexible because you can add extra parameters.
- foreach iterates over every item in the array and you don't need to worry about the array index. If you wish to use the array index, just change `foreach($array as $value)` to `foreach($array as $index => $value)` and you can use the `$index`.
- This method is the most efficient & easiest to read solution to the problem of those provided so far - and solves the answer in the fewest lines of code.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @yivi - Agree with you, but didn't think it was necessary to state the obvious as code is pretty self documenting. However, I have taken your point on board and added a few bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
$tabs = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"); // array of tables

$basequery = "SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM "; // example query
foreach ($tabs as $tab){
   $query = $basequery." `".$tab."`";
}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

first, instead of sizeof(), use count()

You probably noticed its the $i+1 within your str_replace that causes the error.  I would have written the code more like:

`$tabs = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl');
$query = 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM :table:';
foreach($tabs as $i => $tab) {
    $sql = str_replace(':table:', $tab, $query);
    echo $sql; // for debugging
    // ... execute ...
}`

This avoids any issue with array indexes by using a foreach and a second variable to store the desired query string ($sql).

Answer (score -1):

I'd do two things in your code: first i'd use `count` since `sizeof` is an alias for `count` and i'd assign it to a variable since as per Php manual this will lead to a better performance. Then I'd use an if to prevent the error. this not to rewrite your code but keep using the `for`

```
$query = "SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `abc`"; // example query
$max = count($tabs);
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++){
    // ... execute ...

    echo $query; // for debugging
    if($tabs[$i+1]<$max){
        $query = str_replace ( $tabs [$i], $tabs [$i+1], $query ); // replacing table names
    }
}
```